# Modifying text using StringBuilder throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

So far I have managed to create my Dataset and write it an an appropriate format to my text file. Now I need to further modify the contents of that file to include some additional formatting. I'm currently trying to use StringBulders to do so, but whenever I compile the program to test it it throws an OutofRange exception when it hits the Remove command.

Code snippet follows:

```
var editing = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\test.txt");

StringBuilder Editions = new StringBuilder(400);

Editions.Append(editing);
Editions.Insert(0, "0");
Editions.Insert(1, "0");
Editions.Remove(9, 14); // <== exception here
Editions.Insert(11, "R");
Editions.Insert(12, "M");
Editions.Insert(13, "A");
Editions.Insert(14, "L");
Editions.Insert(15, "L");
Editions.Insert(16, " ");
Editions.Insert(17, " ");
Editions.Insert(18, " ");
Editions.Insert(193, "C");
Editions.Insert(194, "L");
Editions.ToString();
```

Comment: LanSlyde - I've removed extra "thank you notes" and whitespace from the post. Also added comment that I believe refers to place that fails. Please confirm changes are fine and additionally show value of `editing` inline in the post (assuming it is relatively short based on error).

Comment: @GrantWinney assuming "when it hits the Remove command" is true there is exactly one `.Remove` call in the code, so I've marked it as such (to also align with given answers :) )

Comment: Huh, thanks for that Alexei. Changes are fine, I'm just trying to sound informal and avoid coming across as demanding.

Comment: @LanSlyde - Check out [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266525/being-polite-while-asking-a-question/266531#266531) discussion on META to see what is considered polite on SO.

Comment: Alright, your previous answer worked, so I will accept it and post a new question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The call to `File.ReadAllLines()` returns a string array.

When you append the string array directly to the StringBuilder using the `Append()` method, it implicitly calls `ToString()` on the string array, which stores the full class name for a string array in your StringBuilder.

In other words, this is the problem, and so the value in your StringBuilder is much shorter than you think:

```
var editing = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.txt");

sb.Append(editing);  // stores "System.String[]"
```

One alternative is to use the method that returns the file as one long string: *(shouldn't be an issue with a file that small, but you probably wouldn't want to read all text at once if it were a huge file)*

```
var editing = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.txt");

sb.Append(editing);  // stores "SampleLine1\r\nSampleLine2\r\nSampleLine3"
```

Comment: I see. Alright, any idea how I could go about correcting that issue?

Comment: @LanSlyde You may view the value of Editions.ToString() in the watch, if the string length is smaller than 23 (9 + 14) while break at Editions.Remove(9, 14), the ArgumentOutOfRangeException will throw.

Comment: Alright,it's no longer throwing an OutOfRange exception, but its also not modifying my file either.

Comment: Editing original post

Answer (score 2):

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

If startIndex or length is less than zero, or startIndex + length is greater than the length of this instance.

[StringBuilder.Remove Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.text.stringbuilder.remove(v=vs.110).aspx)

Better check your C:test.txt before run

Comment: Not sure, the file itself is about 400 characters in length, so I don't think thats the problem.

Comment: So it was not the Remove() cause the exception, it is Insert(). The StringBuilder set as max. capacity as 400 and your file already 400, you can't insert any more character.

Comment: Perhaps, but I have a reference manual sitting in front of me telling me that StringBuilder automatically increases its capacity when necessary. Are you certain that is the problem?

Comment: Opps, I mixed up with the max capacity with the initial capacity, you are right, the StringBuilder will adjust the size as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Because the string isn't that long

Comment: The test.txt file I point to is long enough. So unless its not Appending my variable into my StringBuilder correctly I don't think that is the case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your text file is C:\\test.txt   and the file you are reading doesn't exist, and hence there's nothing read into yor stringbuilder